# PagerAdapter and ViewPager start a new fragment over the current visible view

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager with a PagerAdapter that is called from another fragment, a main fragment if you will.
My PagerAdapter is showing the user images and the user can swipe between them using ViewPager.
I've registered an onClick listener for every image and it seems to work as expected, at least it returns the correct position if I debug the position from instantiateItem.
The problem is that this onClick is supposed to start a new fragment, like an overlay over the image that the user clicked on but it doesn't start the fragment over the current image that the user clicked on for some reason.

Example of what I mean:

On **page one** onClick it starts the fragment at the correct position, (overlaying the current visible view).
On **page two** onClick  it starts the fragment on page 1 (not in the visible view and not where the onClick fired).
On **page three** onClick  it starts the fragment on page 2 (not in the visible view and not where the onClick fired).

Code:

MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(getActivity(), getContext(), stringFetchedName, stringFetchedUserID, stringFetchedUsername, stringFetchedRating, stringFetchedDescription, stringFetchedDate);
    viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
    }
}
```

SwipeAdapter.java

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    FragmentActivity activity;
    Context context;
    String names[], userid[], username[], rating[], description[], date[];
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ImageView imageView;
    public View itemView;

  public SwipeAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, Context context, String names[], String userid[], String username[], String rating[], String description[], String date[]) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.username = username;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = date;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

   @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

   @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

   @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.imageswap, container, false);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        container.addView(itemView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (itemView.findViewById(R.id.userText).isShown()) {
                    showImageOverlay(v);
                } else {
                    hideImageOverlay(v);
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)    {
            container.removeView((View) object);
           }
       }

      public void showImageOverlay(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = new ImageOverlayFragment().newInstance("0", "0");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.imageSwap, fragment, IMAGE_OVERLAY);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

      public void hideImageOverlay(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(IMAGE_OVERLAY);
        if(fragment != null) {
 activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

**How can I make sure that the new fragment ImageOverlayFragment I start is started on top of the image that was clicked, like how could I take the position from instantiateItem into account etc? or what should I do?**

If I debug `Log.d("debug", "Clicked position:" + position);` inside the imageView OnClickListener it gives me the correct position but when I call showImageOverlay(v), it seems like it always starts the fragment on the view to the left of my currently visual view?

Note:
I'm passing a FragmentActivity to the SwipeAdapter from the MainFragment which is why I can access getSupportFragmentManager().

**Update:**

I tried to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter` as suggested by SO and the result is still the same. The onClick event is sending the correct position and I can toggle the visibility of visible elements within the onClick event etc but I still cannot start the new fragment over the view of where the user clicked. The new fragment still starts to the left, and not in the view of where the user clicked. Problem still remains.

Comment: I apologize if the description is confusing but that might be because I am very confused right now because I have no idea why my code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.imageSwap, fragment, IMAGE_OVERLAY);
```

You are using your activity's *TransactionManager* to start you overlay fragment. In the above code, what I am guessing is that you are giving the ID of the container viewgroup of , parent of *ImageView* in its layout file. In a *ViewAdapter* not the currently visible fragment is initialized or view is inflated, but adjacent fragments/views also. That means your view hierarchy from activity root contains more than one layout with the ID you provide for fragment transaction. When activity searches its view hierarchy, it will return the first view it reaches with given ID. In your case, when you are not on the first page of adapter, this first matching view will be inside the leftmost page inside *ViewPager*. ViewPager - by default - uses one view on left and one view on right of the visible page in created state. That is why you see your fragment is instantiated on the page before the one you want it to be.

As a solution, you can consider using fragments inside Pager instead of plain views. Every fragment has a 'childFragmentManager' that u can use to start your new fragment upon click.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
R.id.imageSwap is indeed the parent of ImageView.
Is there no way I can work with the ViewPager instead of working against the API?
Are there no ways I can tell the new fragment to start over the current visible item?

I assume that you mean that R.id.imageSwap will return the first ID it finds, and that this is the cause of the problem I'm having?

Comment: I assume that you mean that R.id.imageSwap will return the first ID it finds, and that this is the cause of the problem I'm having?  The exact stating would be: Searching a view with ID `R.id.imageSwap` will find the first view with that ID, and since you are to start searching your **ImageView** above the **ViewPager**, you will always reach the first child view of the **ViewPager**.

Comment: If my suggestion was not clear in my answer, let me restate here: Try using fragments to show with ViewPager, not plain **View**s. Implement `instantiateItem()` of your adapter to return a fragment instance that displays the **ImageView**s. Implement `onClick()` for the ImageView inside that fragment. Then use fragments `getChildFragmentManager()` to execute a fragment transaction in the same way you were doing previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and what worked had much to do with two of the adapter methods:

instantiateItem - "Create the page for the given position."

setPrimaryItem - "Called to inform the adapter of which item is currently considered to be the "primary", that is the one show to the user as the current page."

Because of the way the adapter works, where it instantiates the fragments before they are displayed, the instantiateItem method is called for fragments or slides that are not in view (apart from the first item). If you can override setPrimaryItem, and then leave the UI/view set up in instantiateItem, and then the rest of the logic (listener with the show/hide overlay) in setPrimaryItem, you can make sure the listener and the fragment are set to the currently active view/fragment.

Let me know if that makes sense to you

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It does make sense to me and I tried to move my logic to `setPrimaryItem` and the position it gets is correct but the fragment still starts in the wrong position, one to the left of the visual view even tho the showImageOverlay() is called from `setPrimaryItem`.

Any idea why? I'm so confused.

Comment: After reading the answer from @alperozge I think thats the cause, I would also suggest switching from PagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter as they are designed to handle UI changes and behaviour much better - from the documentation - "Base class providing the adapter to populate pages inside of a ViewPager. You will most likely want to use a more specific implementation of this, such as androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter or androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter."

Comment: I have updated my question. The problem still remains using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The new fragment always starts one to the left :(